# Scan system PATH for executable file

Tags: scala, process, shutil, notify-send

Python 3 has the very useful `shutil.which` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.which) function. Is there an equivalent for Scala?

For context, I want to run a shell command in scala to get a notification to the user. For example, in the case of ubuntu, something like `Seq("notify-send", title, msg) !` (using `sys.process` from the standard library). But I want to check beforehand if `command` is in the system path, so I can give an informative error message.

I'd like to avoid resorting to parsing (i.e. splitting on `:`) and iterating over the folders manually. Another alternative would be `Seq("which", "command") !`, but that doesn't work on windows (right?).

Comment: Perhaps prox could help? https://vigoo.github.io/prox/docs/

Comment: If this question is about Ammonite (or some other specific tool) you may have a higher change of getting a relevant answer by specifying that and adding the relevant tag(s). `!` is not built-in into Scala.

Comment: @stefanobaghino I have clarified my use case and (standard) library usage. @randbw It seems prox does not have `which`-like functionality, but maybe I missed it.